# Repeating 2d world

Tags: xna, 2d, infinite-loop, repeat

How to make a 2d world with fixed size, which would repeat itself when reached any side of the map?

When you reach a side of a map you see the opposite side of the map which merged togeather with this one. The idea is that if you didn't have a minimap you would not even notice the transition of map repeating itself.

I have a few ideas how to make it: 
1) Keeping total of 3x3 world like these all the time which are exactly the same and updated the same way, just the players exists in only one of them. 
2) Another way would be to seperate the map into smaller peaces and add them to required place when asked. 
Either way it can be complicated to complete it. I remember that more thatn 10 years ago i played some game like that with soldiers following each other in a repeating wold shooting other AI soldiers.
Mostly waned to hear your thoughts about the idea and how it could be achieved. I'm coding in XNA(C#).

Comment: Do you have to display the map continously scrolling? Or the screen is switching at the point of transition? The map is one screen wide or you're displaying only a part of it at a time? Or `merged togeather with this one.` means you want to zoom out and show more once the edge is reached?

Comment: Well map is not scrolling by it self. Player is just freely running around and in case he is close to side of map, he can see the beginning of opposite side. Camera is fixed to player position but map is way larger than the camera screen. I cant figure out if the map should be switching at the border of map or camera, and how the things should work. Regardless, when the edge is reached i want to be able to see opposite side, and also cross over as well.
here is image which might help to understand the idea:
http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/6190/fullyt.jpg

Comment: So the camera is following the player and he is always at the center? The game is tile based?

Comment: Most likely tile based. oh and forgot to mention that camera is from top. Don't know word for it, but u are like watching from sky like in strategy games or whatever. And yes, camera is following and always in center of player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the game is tile based I think what you should do is:

- Keep only one array for the game area.
- Determine the visible area using modulo arithmetics over the size of the game area mod w and h where these are the width and height of the table.
  E.g. if the table is 80x100 (0,0) top left coordinates with a width of 80 and height of 100 and the rect of the viewport is at (70,90) with a width of 40 and height of 20 you index with [70-79][0-29] for the x coordinate and [90-99][0-9] for the y. This can be achieved by calculating the index with the following formula:
   
  `idx = (n+i)%80` (or%100) where `n` is the top coordinate(x or y) for the rect and  `i` is in the range for the width/height of the viewport.
- This assumes that one step of movement moves the camera with non fractional coordinates.

So this is your second alternative in a little bit more detailed way. If you only want to repeat the terrain, you should separate the contents of the tile. In this case the contents will most likely be  generated on the fly since you don't store them.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Got a bit lost about thous number like "with 80w and 100h"
and instead of "[70-79][0-30]" shouldn't it be "[70-99][0-9]"?
Over all basically you suggest to have just one map, and if viewport crosses edge of map then draw the tiles from this map which actualy are not there, but take them from array[tile-map size], where 'tile' is expected tile in that position like 101 or something like that outside actual array.

Comment: Those are just abbreviations (width of 80), updated the answer. Anyway, yes, that's what modulo does.  (I also messed up the numbers, now they are correct)

Comment: Ok thanks, thats pretty much clear for now. Another troublesome thing might be when one side of map is going to interact with other, for example like shooting and units following each other, but probably thats most likely gonna bet just chunks of code and ifs. K TNX BYE

Comment: One more thing you should not forget is that subtraction substitudes modulo only if you have one 'pass', i.e. if you actual coordinates abe between (0,2x) and (0, 2y). Otherwise you'll index out.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to generate noise using libnoise libraries.  The beauty of this is that you can generate noise over a theoretical infinite amount of space.

Take a look at the following:
http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial3.html#tile

There is also an XNA port of the above at:  http://bigblackblock.com/tools/libnoisexna

If you end up using the XNA port, you can do something like this:

```
Perlin perlin = new Perlin();
perlin.Frequency = 0.5f;                //height
perlin.Lacunarity = 2f;                 //frequency increase between octaves
perlin.OctaveCount = 5;                 //Number of passes
perlin.Persistence = 0.45f;             //
perlin.Quality = QualityMode.High;
perlin.Seed = 8;

//Create our 2d map
Noise2D _map = new Noise2D(CHUNKSIZE_WIDTH, CHUNKSIZE_HEIGHT, perlin);

//Get a section
_map.GeneratePlanar(left, right, top, down);
```

GeneratePlanar is the function to call to get the sections in each direction that will connect seamlessly with the rest of your world.

Comment: I have never used these kind of things yet. Sounds complicated.
About my original idea i kinda managed to pull it of quite easy.
Youtube link of how it looks so far: http://youtu.be/2-bT3KtW5ko

Comment: @Sunder This is a much better solution than the modulo I proposed so you should try it. More scalable for bigger projects.